# Download Spotify on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: spotify

I am a self-employed I.T. I was wondering if there was a way to download Spotify to Ubuntu Linux. I have the newest update.

Thanks,
Hunter

Answer (score 2):

You can install spotify with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free" 
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 94558F59 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

Comment: Doesn't the linux client only works for pay accounts?

Comment: Have not used it in a long while, but I don't think so.

Comment: @xangua Spotify works on Linux for free accounts! there's one thing you won't be able to keep the audio tracks as you have to pay for that and it requires pay account. ;)